# How to wrap Text in Flutter on a character basis (without breaking at spaces or '-')?

Tags: flutter, text

When using a Text() widget, if it's wider than the space it has to be rendered, it is wrapped to fill multiple lines. This wrapping seems to be done based on words or some separators, like ' ' or '-', but not for other special characters like '.', ',', '_'.

It so happens I need to present some data that can be quite wide, but it's not natural language, let's say it's just an ID that can contain '-'. I want to be wrapped as if it didn't have any separator characters, but I can't find any option to control that. I see there is a `overflow` option, some `softWrap` too, but nothing seems to be changing the wrapping as I need it to.

Example:

```
Text('aaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-cccccccccccccccccc-ddddddddd');

This is what I get:         This is what I want:
+------------------------+  +------------------------+
| aaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-     |  | aaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-cccc |
| cccccccccccccccccc-    |  | cccccccccccccc-ddddddd |
| ddddddddd              |  | dd                     |
+------------------------+  +------------------------+
```

Comment: try using non breaking Hyphen (\u2011), `Text('aaaaaaaaa\u2011bbbbbbb\u2011cccccccccccccccccc\u2011ddddddd')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the text to show is not under my control. I guess I could replace the chars only for displaying them but is rather ugly. I hope there is a way to just change the chars flutter use for breaking when wrapping instead.

Comment: Since there seems to be no solution for now, I'm using this trick for now, but unfortunately I think I will just need to keep showing the ugly wrapping instead, as I want to present long URLs and them to be selectable (and copiable), so if I replace random characters I'm breaking the URLs :(

Answer (score 0):

This is sadly not possible in Flutter for the time being. There is a feature request for it though: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61081

Answer (score 0):

I have published this package in pub. The MagicText widget solves your problem.

The package is a auto-responsive text widget that supports a multitude of parameters to control text rendering behaviour. You can control line breaks that break words in half with a given character (default is '-').

Pub package:
[MagicText Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/magic_text)

Instance MagicText widget example:

```
  const MagicText magicText = MagicText(
  "Your text here.",
  breakCharacter: '-',
  smartSizeMode: true,
  asyncMode: true,
  minFontSize: 20,
  maxFontSize: 40,
  textStyle: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20, //It is mandatory that the textStyle has a fontsize.
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
  ),
);
```

[Mobile app example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgxL9.gif)